# <a> tag on new window opens both blank and self

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages on my webpage. I have a link in one of the pages which open the other page in a new window with this code:

```js
function  openNewPage() {
  window.open(
      URL,
      "_blank",
      "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=600,width=850,height=600"
  );
}
```

```html
{{-- Click to go to next page --}}

<a onClick="openNewPage()"
  class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill">
  <i class="fa fa-comment"
    style="color: red;font-weight: bold;">
    <span class="unread_number">Go to second page</span>
  </i>
</a>
```

When the new window opens the second page, I have another link there that opens the first page.

```html
{{-- This is the second page which after click should go to first page again --}}
<a href="/first_page">
    <i class="la la-angle-right" ></i>
</a>
```

The issue is when it has no target the page will open in both _self page and a new tab on the parent page.
when I set **target="self"** it acts exactly the same way when I don't set target.
I need the page will be open only on the self window which opens before.
Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please add executable code to debug better

Comment: this shouldn't happen as I can understand with the limited information you've provided. Please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so as to get better help

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I edited my question. I don't know how to explain it more because in the real project there are tones of codes. I simplified this part.

Comment: @AmitSharma I edited my codes. Is it better?

Comment: Your second page opened in a new tab and you want this new page opens the previous page in the previous  tab not a new tab. am I right?

Comment: Does using target="_top" help you?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Nop. I want to open the second page on the self tab. I mean where the second page opened.

Comment: @TusharShahi It didn't work. I want to open it in the self tab

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand what you expect. Page A opens B(in a new tab). Now B has a link to Page A, when you click on this link it goes to Page A(in the same tab where Page B opened). Can you explain which part of this you want/expect to act differently.

Comment: I solve my issue with window.open(URL, "_self") without using a tag.

Comment: @TusharShahi Page A opens page  B (in a new window). I have an Icon on page B that user click should open page A again but not in a new tab, in the window that page B is opened before.
the issue is when I click on the icon on B page the link will open both in a new tab and page B window. Do you get it?